# Why does the subclass in this Java code have a default constructor if the super-class does not have one?

Tags: java, constructor

I have looked around for the answer to this question, but so far I haven't understood this. I have 3 Java classes, BinaryTree and HuffmanTree (which extends BinaryTree) and HuffmanData (used in HuffmanTree, irrelevant to this question)

HuffmanTree explicitly calls super() in its constructors. What I am unable to understand is why does it include a call to the default constructor? The superclass BinaryTree does not have a default constructor at all, so according to my understanding the code should throw an Exception, but it doesn't.

Here is the code for BinaryTree :

```
public class BinaryTree {
    private Comparable data;
    private BinaryTree left;
    private BinaryTree right;
    public final static BinaryTree NIL = new BinaryTree(null, null, null);

    // Constructor 1
    public BinaryTree (Comparable data, BinaryTree left, BinaryTree right) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    // Constructor 2
    public BinaryTree (Comparable data) {
        this(data, BinaryTree.NIL, BinaryTree.NIL);
    }
    .
    .
    . // other methods
}
```

And here is the code for HuffmanTree :

```
public final class HuffmanTree extends BinaryTree implements Comparable {
    private String[] table;
    private static final int NUM_CHARS = 256;
    private static final HuffmanTree NIL = new HuffmanTree();
              // Calls default constructor in this class, but how does it work?

    // Constructor 1 --- what does this do??
    private HuffmanTree() {}

    // Constructor 2
    private HuffmanTree (char c, int f) {
        super(new HuffmanData(c,f), NIL, NIL);
    }

    // Constructor 3 
    private HuffmanTree (HuffmanTree left, HuffmanTree right) {
        super(new HuffmanData( (char)0, left.frequency()+right.frequency()),
                                                 left, right);
    }
    .
    .
    . // other methods
}
```

Apologies if the question is unclear. Please let me know how I can explain it better.

Answer (score 2):

This my friend would produce a compiler error `no suitable constructor found for BinaryTree()`.

A default no-arg constructor would be created for a Class only if you don't provide any constructor for the class. If you provide a constructor to the class, then you have to create a no-arg constructor on your own.

[**JLS**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) states that

> It is a compile-time error if a default constructor is implicitly declared but the superclass does not have an accessible constructor (§6.6) that takes no arguments and has no throws clause.

Comment: Does this mean that the no-args constructor on Object is obscured as soon as you provide a default ctor? . . (Its been a few years since I've done Java - must be getting rusty!)

Comment: when you create a constructor for your class, the compiler doesn't insert any default no-arg constructor. but what the compiler does is put a call to the super class constructor by inserting `super()` in your constructor, provided you do not extend any other class without a no-arg constructor.

Comment: Although I agree with your answer, your JLS quote does not apply to this case.  The default constructor of `HuffmanTree` is not *implicitly* declared, it is *explicitly* declared.

Comment: i agree that this doesn't apply to the case, but i included this to give an idea of how it works.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! However, when my professor executed this in class, no errors or exceptions were there. Perhaps I made a mistake, but your explanation makes sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

The private no-args constructor does nothing useful except cause a compilation error. Looks like somebody's attempt to make it unusable by making it private, but the presence of the other constructor already prevents the compiler from generating a default constructor.

I don't know why you think an exception will be thrown, unless you're confusing exceptions and compile errors. Compile errors are not exceptions, and they are printed, not thrown.

Comment: This does not expalain why no exception is thrown.

Comment: what do you mean by the super() call does nothing useful..? the compiler inserts a no-arg super calls for you and if your super class doesn't have any no-arg constructor, it will result in a compile time error.

Answer (score -3):

In Java, default constructor is automatically created by JVM whether you write it or not. So in your code for class of BinaryTree default constructor is automatically created and when object of HuffmanTree calls default constructor it calls default constructor of BinaryTree.

Comment: First sentence is only correct if you don't provide any other constructors.